# Is there any way to retrieve type or price of available phone number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Lets say i got only number and isoCountry for example:

```
    String number = +43720116398;
    String isoCountry = "AT";
```

And i'm trying to determine the price or type before buying.
I want to know if that number is LOCAL, MOBILE or TOLL_FREE.

Sadly Lookups client doesnt work in this case:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    LookupsClient client = new LookupsClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    PhoneNumber number = client.getPhoneNumber(number , true);
    System.out.println(number.getType());
  }
```

It return diffrent kind of types or nulls.
If i could get type/price of Incoming Phone Number that would also satisfied me.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i know that number is LOCAL or MOBILE so i just check if this number with LOCAL type exist if doesnt its MOBILE, you can easily add checking if its TOLL_FREE or MOBILE if you want to.
If someone provide cleaner way to do it within couple days i will gladly accept his answer if not i will accept mine.

Runnable example:

```
public class Main {
    private final static String MOBILE = "MOBILE";
    private final static String LOCAL = "LOCAL";
    private static TwilioRestClient twilioRestClient = new TwilioRestClient("Key", "key");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "+43720116398";
        String isoCountry = "AT";
        getMsisdnType(number, isoCountry);
    }


    public static String getMsisdnType(String msisdn, String isoCountry) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Contains", msisdn);
        Optional<AvailablePhoneNumber> number = twilioRestClient.getAccount().getAvailablePhoneNumbers(params, isoCountry, LOCAL).getPageData().stream().findAny();
        if (number.isPresent()) return LOCAL;
        return MOBILE;
    }
}
```